# No test is available. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I have created REST API framework in visual studio 2017 C#.
I have created Just created one single test method using MSTest Framework and which is listed in Test Explorer But when I run it, it is giving me output details as below-

Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise: No test is available. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

[image]

Test Class- 
[image]

- I tried to Change Platform from 64 to x86 i.e. 32 bit for Project and vice versa
- Tried to change default processor architecture form Test setting to X86
- From Application Pool setting in ISS , tried with setting 32 bit
- Tried to install ASP.Net.Core. 2.0.0 , 2.1.0, 2.2.0, no luck
- Sometime giving compatibility issue for this DLL
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

Try to update after removing above DLL and install 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.Updated , but not able to install it

Got error as below while installing Nuget -
Error   NU1202  Package VS.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework 15.0.27323.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package VS.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework 15.0.27323.2 supports: microsoftvisualstudioqualitytoolsunittestframeworkdll (Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll,Version=v0.0) REST.API.Automation.Framework

- Tried in debug mode
- Tried with adding NunitTest, NunitTestAdapter3 even if i am using MSTest Framework
- Looks like there might be SDK ASP.Net.Core2 compatibility issue or
- TestSetting file is not supported
- References folder is not displayed after adding references, everything is going under Assembly folder

Comment: How did you create your unit test project? Did you use the MSTest Test Project (.NET Core) or something else? What package references do you have in the project?

Comment: I have used Ms Test Project not .Net Core

Comment: If you didn't add a .NET Core app I'm confused by your attempts to add .NET Core references and the .NETCoreApp errors. Are you testing a NET Core or a .NET Framework app?

Comment: See when i created mstest project then sdk called netcore app is automatically added. I have nothing to do with it. I am.not doing anything related to that

Comment: As that sdk is getting added automatically it is showing some compatible issue with one of the reference called quality.unittestingframework , i am also confused why that sdk is getting added even if i have created plain mstest project in vsts 2017

Comment: When you say added automatically, it's added when automatically? When you created the project in Visual Studio or when you added a reference to the project you are going to test?

Comment: When i created new project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196659/discussion-between-simond-and-robb-vandaveer).

Answer (score 6):

Try build the project in release mode and then again build the project in Debug mode.
Run the Test suite....Hope it will work

Comment: It is magic. wow